# How to configure the React Browserrouter with Apache2 and Subdirectories

Tags: reactjs, apache, ubuntu

I have my react website on my ubuntu server where apache2 is installed.
I already added a `.htaccess` file with the code `FallbackResource /index.html`
and I also changed the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` file.

My website is also working to a certain level because when I open the url : `my_domain.com/login` 
everything is working.

But if I open a url like: `my_domain.com/login/verify` my website only shows a blank page.
Why?

I also changed my `.htaccess` file to :

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

still not working

This is my console if the page is blank:
[image]

Comment: What does the browser dev tools console contain?

Comment: Hi, I added the picture to my question

Comment: It appears you are making an AJAX request to and endpoint that is returning your index.html file. That means the server does not recognize the endpoint URL - so, it is doing what you've asked - sends back index.html. The error indicates this with the "unexpected token '<' bit.

Comment: And how can I change this?

Comment: The rewrite condition says if the file name requested cannot be found, send the `index.html` file and end the transfer. Your request for `my_domain.com/login/verify` is to a file that cannot be found. You'll need to resolve that in one of many ways that cannot be determined given the info in  your question.